# Remove the "microsoft-acount" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we remove the [microsoft-acount](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-acount) tag as it's just an improperly spelled version of the [microsoft-account](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-account) tag?  There was only one question using the tag and it has an edit request in to fix the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that we can delete tags. But it will get automatically deleted at some stage now that you have re-tagged it....as long as the tag remains inactive.

Comment: This is correct. Unused tags are removed periodically and automatically. No further action is required.